# Any reason why I can SSH from server terminal to remote machine but putty wont work?

Tags: networking, ssh, remote-desktop, putty, redhat-enterprise-linux

So the title basically describes the issue, however here is a more elaborate breakdown. I can SSH into the remote machine from a local terminal, however I cant putty into the remote machine. I'm not sure why this is, considering putty is using SSH as its protocol to connect to the remote machine. In both cases the IP is the same. Whats really odd is that it only started happening once I set the IP to static on the remote machine. I'm thinking maybe after I set the IP static on the remote machine the DHCP server Hi-jacked it instantly and gave it to something else? However there shouldn't be anything else taking that IP as the network is only about 20 machines and all of them are satisfied with IP's already. not to mention I can SSH into the remote server via terminal using:

```
 ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

and it logs me into the remote machine I am trying to access. Is there anything different about Putty SSH that I am missing? Any advice would be great!!

(*update: I cant WinSCP to the server either but sftp does work from local terminal*)

Comment: You didn't mention _anything_ about what happens when you try to use PuTTY. Do you get an error message? Do you see anything in PuTTY's "Event Log"? Can you successfully `plink -v root@xxxx.xxxx.xxxx`?

Comment: Yes show us PuTTY event log (or `plink -v` output as hinted by @grawity)  and output of `ssh -v root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`.

Comment: I feel like what version of ssh the server is running and what version of putty may be helpful here...

Comment: hi there Tim, I am running red hat 7.5 on the server, not sure if that comes with any standard version of SSH? and I believe its the latest version of putty

Answer (score 0):

PuTTY retries its connection (picking the ssh key from the collection in Pageant), while your other client may not (or may have only one key): the retries can cause a connection failure.

Comment: So would that mean that it worked via dhcp because it registered a key while it was under dhcp, and now that it has switched to static the key is not matching?

Comment: This make no sense to me. How can a retry cause connection failure? Why would PuTTY not connect on the first attempt already as `ssh` seemingly does? Moreover PuTTY does not really retry connection. It may do several authentication attempts (using different keys or key(s) and then password, etc), but still over the same connection.

Comment: It'll fail when the remote server is setup to deny on successful failures (if PuTTY happens to chose a key first that doesn't work), e.g., `MaxAuthTries`.  On some systems (using winbind), I've found it to lock the account for a while.  Of course this may not be OP's problem, but it's what I've found in practice.

Comment: but how would it be setup do deny on successful failures? I don't follow? and if so then that would mean the solution is to reset the putty key(s)? Basically don't allow putty to have any old key to begin with and register the new key when u attempt to connect as static? to elaborate more, essentially what I understood was that putty doesn't "retry" a full connection process, is simply tries to re-authenticate. If that was the case wouldn't closing putty or using the "new session" option attempt to open a completely new connection? then the question of will a new machine an putty session work?